# Angular 6 and NodeJS - how to clean cache?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am using NodeJS to host Angular app (all bundled in one) and starting the app with `npm start` which builds Angular and run it along with NodeJS server.

But seems that after changing angular code (one of .ts files) - node is keep loading old file from `server/public/main.d71b1f06ef7e78fdba3f.js` rather than from a new build.

Tried `npm cache clean --force` but that did not change anything.

How to force `re-building` and displaying changes in UI after changing files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh your browser with `Shift`+`F5` ([for Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?visit_id=636758507668674696-227395898&hl=en&rd=2)) or `Ctrl`+`F5` (for Firefox) ?

So it will ignore the cached content when refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added HMR? I don't think HMR is playing a role.
[This link](http://HTTPS://GITHUB.COM/ANGULAR/ANGULAR-CLI/WIKI/STORIES-CONFIGURE-HMR) may help you